# Inject variable from service in environment.ts

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have an Angular 5 app which needs to load some config files from a service (from VSTS) before the app actually starts. I do this by loading a JSON file on bootstrap in app.module.ts:

```
// above the NgModule-decorator
export function init(settingsProvider: SettingsProvider) {
  return () => settingsProvider.loadConfig();
}

// in providers-array of the @NgModule decorator
providers: [{
    'provide': APP_INITIALIZER,
    'useFactory': init,
    'deps': [SettingsProvider],
    'multi': true
}
```

This loads a JSON config file inside the settingsProvider (which is a standard service loading a JSON file).
Now I need some parameters of this settingsProvider within my environment variables.

(let me show you my **settingsProvider:**)

```
@Injectable()
export class SettingsProvider {

  private config : any;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  public loadConfig() : Promise<any>{
    return this.http.get("assets/client-config.json")
      .map(res => res.json())
      .toPromise()
      .then(settings => {
        this.config = settings
      });
  }

  public get configuration(): any {
    return this.config;
  }
}
```

But since the environment.ts is just a constant, I cannot inject any service there.

So my desired solution would be something like this:

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiBaseUrl: '/',
  clientId: settingsProvider.configuration.clientId,  // <-- Here's the problem, because I cannot inject settingsProvider
  enableAdalDebug: false
};
```

Does anyone know a solution for that problem?

Comment: Hi, there is a good reason why the environment file is constant. But as I understand you correctly, you already inject the `SettingsProvider`. Is it not possible to inject the `SettingsProvider` (which holds the `clientId`) into your services or components, where you need the `clientId`?

Comment: No, I haven't injected it yet. I'm using the variable in another service which sends config information to Azure AD for login. Actually I never change a value of the constant, since the settingsProvider information is loaded while bootstrapping. So I just need a way to inject a service in the environment.ts :)

Comment: I don't think that this is possible, but tell me if you find a solution!

Comment: Can you provide the detail workflow of your app?